# CNN Model can't predict images outside the dataset (FaceMask Detection)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

i wonder why my cnn model cant predict images outside the dataset ???

my model have **val_accuracy at 98.6%** and **val_loss at 0.05**

i tested my model with 827 test_images from my dataset, 816 of them are correct.
but when i do a test at image that i download outside the dataset, my model can't predict correctly.

this is my **CNN Model** (Code with kaggle notebook):

```
# import the necessary packages
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV2, EfficientNetB6
from tensorflow.keras.layers import AveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
# from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import keras as k
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam, Adagrad, RMSprop
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
from keras.models import load_model, Model
from keras.regularizers import L2, L1, L1L2
import pickle
from IPython.display import FileLink

dir = "D:\Prototype 2\dataset"

data = []
labels = []

categories = ["with_mask", "without_mask"]

 for category in categories:
     print(category)
     path = os.path.join(dir, category)
     for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_path = os.path.join(path, img)
        image = load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
        image = img_to_array(image)
        image = image / 255.0

        data.append(image)
        labels.append(category)

one_encode = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
labels = np.reshape(labels, (len(labels), 1))
labels = one_encode.fit_transform(labels)

data = np.array(data)
labels = np.array(labels)


(train_images, test_images, train_labels, test_labels) = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.20, stratify=labels, random_state=42)


datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=20,
    zoom_range=0.15,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.15,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode="nearest")
datagen.fit(train_images)

reg=None
breg=L2(0.01)
num_filters=100
ac='relu'
adm=Adam(lr=0.0001,decay=0, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08)
sgd = SGD(learning_rate=0.0001, momentum=0, decay=0)
rms = RMSprop(lr= 0.0001, epsilon=1e-08)
opt=adm
drop_dense=0.5
drop_conv=0

model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Conv2D(num_filters, (3, 3), activation=ac,input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Conv2D(num_filters, (3, 3), activation=ac))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size= (2,2)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))


model.add(layers.Conv2D(2*num_filters, (3, 3), activation=ac))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Conv2D(2*num_filters, (3, 3), activation=ac))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size= (2,2)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))


model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))

model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation=ac, kernel_regularizer=reg))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))


model.summary()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'],optimizer=adm)
history=model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=32),
                    steps_per_epoch = len(train_images) / 32, epochs=100, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))


loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
print("Accuracy is : ", accuracy * 100)


# plot loss
plt.subplot(211)
plt.title('Cross Entropy Loss')
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], color='blue', label='train')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], color='orange', label='test')
# plot accuracy
plt.subplot(212)
plt.title('Classification Accuracy')
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], color='blue', label='train')
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], color='orange', label='test')
# save plot to file
# filename = sys.argv[0].split('/')[-1]
plt.savefig("plot.png")
FileLink(r'plot.png')



model.save("Mask_model.h5") # serialize weights to HDF5


FileLink(r'Mask_model.h5')
```

This is my Prediction with test_images (splited dataset):

```
path_data = '../input/dataaaa/data2.pkl' #list of all images in array that i saved with pickle
path_label = '../input/lablee/lable.pkl' #list of all labels that i saved with pickle (with_mask and without mask)

open_file_data = open(path_data, "rb")
data = pickle.load(open_file_data)
open_file_data.close()

open_file_label = open(path_label, "rb")
labels = pickle.load(open_file_label)
open_file_label.close()

one_encode = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
labels = np.reshape(labels, (len(labels), 1))
labels = one_encode.fit_transform(labels)

data = np.array(data)
labels = np.array(labels)


(train_images, test_images, train_labels, test_labels) = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.20, stratify=labels, random_state=42)

correct = 0

for i in range (test_images.shape[0]):
    if y_test[i] == y_pred[i]:
        print("Actual : " , y_test[i] , "Predict : ", y_pred[i])
        correct+= 1
print("Total Test Data : ", test_images.shape[0])

print("Correct : ", correct)
```

This is The Output :

```
Total Test Data : 827
Correct :  816
```

Testing with image that i downloaded :

```
img = load_img('../input/testt2/mask.jpg') #mask image
img = img.resize((224,224))
img_array = img_to_array(img)
img = img_array / 255.0 #normalize
img = np.expand_dims(img, 0) #adding to 4d

model = load_model("../input/modell/Mask_modeladamownpreprocesbatchnormalize.h5")
pred = model.predict(img)
y_pred = [np.argmax(element) for element in pred]
print(y_pred)
```

Output :

```
# [0] is a mask image, [1] is a no mask image
[1]
```

Comment: How many images are there in training?

Comment: Colours of the masks matter I think. If your dataset consist only black or white masks for example, you won't be able to predict yellow masks I think. That's considered bias in ML.

Comment: Can you tell us about the properties of the training images dataset, test images dataset, and the images you used to test that's outside of both?

Comment: @AmitKanderi i have 3306 training images

Comment: @ZimingShan i mixed my dataset, but mostly my dataset is from mr.Balaji Srinivasan https://github.com/balajisrinivas/Face-Mask-Detection on github and kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/andrewmvd/face-mask-detection

Comment: @Frightera my dataset have a lot of mask variation (medical, scuba, etc) and colour

Comment: is it my sigmoid activation that cause the problem ??

Comment: @WillyWijaya Yes sigmoid function may cause the error here, I missed it in the first place. Try model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) since you are doing binary classification.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is usually the result of having some difference between the nature of your training images that are provided to model.fit and the images you are attempting to predict. Make sure of the following
predict images shape should be the same as train image shape
pixel values should be scaled identically
color order rgb must be in same order or both in greyscale
You seem to have an adequate size data set. Sometimes the problem can be that there is a significantly different probability distribution in the nature of your training set and the images you are trying to predict. One thing to do is to take a few of your training images and use them as an input for your predictions if they do not get predicted correctly then the problem is as described above. That is something is different in the training pipeline versus the prediction pipeline